# map in header file c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, header-files

Simple question....

I have a header file called bag...

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Bag
{
public:

Bag();


map <const string str, int number> items;

private:

};

#endif
```

In the implementation, I'd like to insert something into bag:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include "Bag.h"

using namespace std;

Bag::Bag()
{
items["brush"] = 4;
}
```

But for some reason, i can't access items.  What am I doing wrong????

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access items"?

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error, post it.

Comment: You have compilation errors in your map declaration.  It should just be `map<string, int>`.  There are some stylistic issues too, but what does the compiler tell you?  What errors do you get after fixing `items` declaration?

Comment: And the template definition should be `std::map<std::string, int>` instead of `int number`

Comment: Duh! For some reason I'm trying to insert a value name with the value type field.  Thanks Chad, I think you fixed me!

Comment: @fefe - not so - he used a horrible using declaration in a header file! :-(

Comment: Yeah, it's never a good idea to use a `using` declaration in a header file. It forces anybody using your header to use the namespace, which they may not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Duh! For some reason I'm trying to insert a value name with the value type field. Thanks Chad, I think you fixed me!

```
map <const string, int> items;
```